# How to properly use React.creatRef()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've been beating my head against the wall and cross referencing code I've read from others and questions that have been asked. I'm at the point where I know I'm just not looking in the right direction, however I'm not sure where to turn.

The app I'm writing was originally written by me in 2019, and I did not know of React h
Hooks as I learned components from a coding bootcamp. TL;DR: I'm rusty.

The issue:
I'm trying to use AXIOS to use a PUT call into my MongoDB, and the way I learned was by using refs. Refs in the way I learned is now deprecated, and I just want to get this working so I can move on to another project and start using Hooks instead.

When I use my button created to save the change, I get an error in the browser console, however it refreshes too fast for me to catch the exact error. The second I get to look at the wall of text, it looks similar to a bad promise, but I'm not entirely sure. Either way, the data does not get updated.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios  from 'axios'

export default class EditSeed extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        _id: '',
        seed: '',
        created_at: '',
        __v: ''
    }

    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)

    this.myRef = React.createRef
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
}

focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchSeed()
}

fetchSeed = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/grapevine/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        this.setState({
            _id: res.data._id ,
            seed: res.data.seed,
            created_at: res.data.created_at,
            __v: res.data.__v
        })
    }
    catch (err) {
        this.setState({ error: err.message })
        console.log(err)
    }
}

editSeed = async (newSeed) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.request({
            method: 'put',
            url: `/api/grapevine/${this.state._id}`,
            data: newSeed
        })
        res.this.props.history.push(`/`)
    }
    catch (err) {
        this.setState({ error: err.message })
        console.log(err)
    }
}

onSubmit = (e) => {
    const newSeed = {
        seed: this.myRef.current.seed.value,
        created_at: this.myRef.current.created_at.value
    }
    this.editSeed(newSeed)
    e.preventDefault()
}

changeHandler = (e) => {
    const target = e.target
    const value = target.value
    const name = target.name

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <h1>Edit Seed</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <label>
                Edit Message:
                <input type="text" name="seed" ref={this.myRef} value={this.state.seed} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

My fetch function works as intended, it's mainly just the edit that doesn't want to work. I have tried changing

```
 <input type="text" name="seed" ref={this.myRef} value={this.state.seed} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
```

to

```
 <input type="text" name="seed" ref={this.myRef.current} value={this.state.seed} onChange={this.changeHandler} />
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong, and I have referenced and read the React docs on this about 10 times and I'm really just hitting a wall.

Any insight would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `React.createRef` is a function, so it needs to be invoked.

```
this.myRef = React.createRef();
```

Then you simply attach the ref to the element.

```
<input
  ref={this.myRef}
  type="text"
  name="seed"
  value={this.state.seed}
  onChange={this.changeHandler}
/>
```

Then whenever you need to reference the input's ref you access the current value of it.

```
this.myRef.current
```

#### Update

I don't think the React ref is providing much for you here since you duplicate the `seed` and `created_at` into local state. You update the `seed` state via the `onChange` handler. Why not just forego the ref and access the state in the submit handler. I believe this will resolve your "cannot access `value` of undefined" error since the `input` element target object likely doesn't have `seed` or `created_at` attributes to access a value of.

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const newSeed = {
    seed: this.state.seed,
    created_at: this.state.created_at // is this supposed to be a current datetime?
  }
  this.editSeed(newSeed);
}

changeHandler = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

Comment: Really can't believe I missed out on that. Thank you. I am getting an undefined error, so I will have to figure it out.

Comment: @Austin What is being reported as undefined?

Comment: @Austin I think it's that the input element won't have a `seed` or `created_at` attribute to access a value of.  Other than when the state is initialized, when is `created_at` updated? I see that the input's `onChange` handles the `seed` state update. Why doesn't the form's `onSubmit` just read from local state? The React ref doesn't seem to be helping you much here.

Comment: Thank you so so much! The refs came from something I was trying out to see if I could get this to work as it was something that worked previously. It led me into this rabbit hole, but your second suggestion of just forgoing the refs in general really helped! Everything is functioning as intended now.

In the future, I'm just going to learn React Hooks, as it seems to be the way things are shifting.

Oh and created at was originally a date and time, yes, but I changed this to be a string on purpose. I may recreate this later.

Comment: @Austin They sure are... I don't think I've written a class-component for a production app in a couple years. When switching to function components and React hooks, be sure to have a good strong grasp of the React component lifecycle, this will help you understand when and what will trigger rerenders and hook dependency updates.

Comment: I appreciate the help and advice Drew, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You did nearly got it right, just a few minor changes will lead you to the right way:

First: You need to invoke React.createRef function:

```
this.myRef = React.createRef -> this.myRef = React.createRef()
```

Second: You need to call e.preventDefault() from the begining of your handler so that the whole page will not get refeshed imediately. Something like this:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newSeed = {
      seed: this.myRef.current.seed.value,
      created_at: this.myRef.current.created_at.value
  }
  this.editSeed(newSeed)
}
```

From then, I think you will easily get to the right path.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` just needs to be called in the callback function, before any asynchronous code if the callback happens to be declared `async`. There's no requirement that it needs to be called first before anything else.

Comment: Great to know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Actually moving the e.preventDefault() to the top of the code actually helped in that I can find the error. 

When I try to update, even after invoking React.createRef as a function, I'm getting at least able to read the message which is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook in functional components like this:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

function MyComponenet () {
  myRef = useRef(null)  // <---- initialize your ref with null

  return (
    <div ref=myRef >
     Hello World
    </div>
  )
}
```

now you create a reference and initiate it with a null value, then passed it to the div element. from now you can manipulate your ref like get its value or assign values, click, and other actions.

**with TypeScript**

```
myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
```

if you are passing `myRef` to a `div` element, so your ref type will be `HTMLDivElement`